# How to create monthly attendance report with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014, crosstab

I have an analyzed table which contains four records of each user per day. I want a monthly report to show the time like below:

```
UserID       [1]     [2]     [3]     [4]......... [End of each month]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1            7:00    7:40    7:20    N/A......... Absence
1            12:00   13:00   12:45   12:50....... Absence
1            14:00   14:10   13:45   N/A......... Absence
1            17:30   17:30   17:45   13:10....... Absence
```

And here is the records that I have:
[image]
So, I started to do some research for several weeks and end up with creating dynamic sql script to create pivot table. The first part my sql is for analyzing the data from my fingerprint device with the duty time of each employee. After the data has been analyzed, I insert it into a table named hrms.AnalyzedRecord which contains all clean records from the device of each user. The script has been written as below:

```
  USE [KCLDB]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [hrms].[GetMonthlyAttedance]    Script Date: 7/27/18 10:21:34 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [hrms].[GetMonthlyAttedance] (@date     DATE = '', 
                                              @location NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
                                              @sortby   SMALLINT = 0) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @from_first_time_in   TIME(7), 
              @to_first_time_in     TIME(7), 
              @from_first_time_out  TIME(7), 
              @to_first_time_out    TIME(7), 
              @from_second_time_in  TIME(7), 
              @to_second_time_in    TIME(7), 
              @from_second_time_out TIME(7), 
              @to_second_time_out   TIME(7), 
              @counter              INT = 0, 
              @first_time_in        TIME(7), 
              @first_time_out       TIME(7), 
              @second_time_in       TIME(7), 
              @second_time_out      TIME(7), 
              @duty_time_in         TIME (7), 
              @duty_time_out        TIME(7), 
              @result_time          INT, 
              @hour                 INT, 
              @minute               INT, 
              @second               INT, 
              @status               NVARCHAR(30), 
              @employee_count       INT,
              @date_range INT, 
              @date_step  INT,
              @built_date   date 
  SELECT @date_range = Datediff(day, @date, Dateadd(MONTH, 1, @date)); 
  print('This is date_range:' + cast(@date_range as nvarchar(max)))

  SELECT @date_step = 1; 

  SELECT @employee_count = Count(EmployeeID) 
  FROM   hrms.Employee 

  --DECLARE @temptable TABLE 
  --  ( 
  --     ID         INT, 
  --     DN         INT, 
  --     UserID     NVARCHAR(10), 
  --     Clock      TIME(7), 
  --     [Date]     DATE, 
  --     [Action]   NVARCHAR(max), 
  --     VerifyMode NVARCHAR(max), 
  --     [Status]   NVARCHAR(30) 
  --  ) 
  WHILE @date_step <= @date_range
    BEGIN
      WHILE @counter < @employee_count 
        BEGIN 
            /*** Getting time to scan of each employee ***/ 
            SELECT @built_date = Cast(Year(@date) AS NVARCHAR(max)) + '-' 
                             + Cast(Month(@date) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '-' 
                             + Cast(@date_step AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            SELECT @from_first_time_in = FromTimeIn 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'AM' 

            SELECT @to_first_time_in = ToTimeIn 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'AM' 

            SELECT @from_first_time_out = FromTimeOut 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'AM' 

            SELECT @to_first_time_out = ToTimeOut 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'AM' 

            SELECT @from_second_time_in = FromTimeIn 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'PM' 

            SELECT @to_second_time_in = ToTimeIn 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'PM' 

            SELECT @from_second_time_out = FromTimeOut 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'PM' 

            SELECT @to_second_time_out = ToTimeOut 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'PM' ---End getting duty time  

        /***   
          - Getting time log and duty time of each employee   
          - Calculating the result and status between duty time and time log of each employee  
          - Save the calculation result  
        ***/ 
            --- Getting time log and duty time [first time in]  
            SELECT @first_time_in = (SELECT TOP 1 Clock 
                                     FROM   hrms.AttendanceRecord 
                                     WHERE  [Date] = @built_date  
                                            AND Clock BETWEEN 
                                                @from_first_time_in 
                                                AND 
                                                @to_first_time_in 
                                            AND UserID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, 
                                                              '00000' 
                                                              ) 
                                                              AS 
                                                              NVARCHAR 
                                                              (10)) 
                                     ORDER  BY ID ASC) 
                                     PRINT('This is the date: ' + cast(@built_date as nvarchar(max)))

            SELECT @duty_time_in = D.BeginTime 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'AM' 

            --- Calculation result and status [first time in]  
            SELECT @result_time = Datediff (SECOND, @duty_time_in, 
                                  ​@first_time_in) 

            SELECT @hour = @result_time / 3600 

            SELECT @minute = ( @result_time % 3600 ) / 60 

            SELECT @second = ( @result_time % 3600 ) % 60 

            SELECT @status = CASE 
                               WHEN ( @first_time_in > @duty_time_in ) THEN ( 
                               N'ចូលយឺត(' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@hour, '00') AS NVARCHAR) + ':' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@minute, '00') AS NVARCHAR) 
                               + ':' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@second, '00') AS NVARCHAR) 
                               + N' វិនាទី)' ) 
                               ELSE '' 
                             END 

            --- Saving result  
            INSERT INTO hrms.AnalyzedRecord
            SELECT TOP 1 ID, 
                         DN, 
                         UserID, 
                         Clock, 
                         [Date], 
                         'In', 
                         VerifyMode, 
                         @status 
            FROM   hrms.AttendanceRecord 
            WHERE  [Date] = @built_date  
                   AND Clock BETWEEN @from_first_time_in AND @to_first_time_in 
                   AND UserID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
            ORDER  BY ID ASC --- saving [1]  

            --- Getting time log and duty time [first time out]  
            SELECT @first_time_out = (SELECT TOP 1 Clock 
                                      FROM   hrms.AttendanceRecord 
                                      WHERE  [Date] = @built_date  
                                             AND Clock BETWEEN 
                                                 @from_first_time_out 
                                                 AND 
                                                 @to_first_time_out 
                                             AND UserID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, 
                                                               '00000') 
                                                               AS 
                                                               NVARCHAR(10)) 
                                      ORDER  BY ID DESC) 

            SELECT @duty_time_out = D.EndTime 
            FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                   JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                     ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                   JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                     ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                   JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                     ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
            WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10) 
                                  ) 
                   AND D.Remark = 'AM' ---end getting log and duty time  

            --- Calculation result and status [first time out]   
            SELECT @result_time = Datediff (SECOND, ​@first_time_out, 
                                  @duty_time_out 
                                  ) 

            SELECT @hour = @result_time / 3600 

            SELECT @minute = ( @result_time % 3600 ) / 60 

            SELECT @second = ( @result_time % 3600 ) % 60 

            SELECT @status = CASE 
                               WHEN ( @first_time_out < @duty_time_out ) THEN ( 
                               N'ចេញមុន(' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@hour, '00') AS NVARCHAR) + ':' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@minute, '00') AS NVARCHAR) 
                               + ':' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@second, '00') AS NVARCHAR) 
                               + N' វិនាទី)' ) 
                               ELSE '' 
                             END --- end calcuation  
            --- Saving result  
            INSERT INTO hrms.AnalyzedRecord 
            SELECT TOP 1 ID, 
                         DN, 
                         UserID, 
                         Clock, 
                         [Date], 
                         'Out', 
                         VerifyMode, 
                         @status 
            FROM   hrms.AttendanceRecord 
            WHERE  [Date] = @built_date  
                   AND Clock BETWEEN @from_first_time_out AND @to_first_time_out 
                   AND UserID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
            ORDER  BY ID DESC --- end saving [2]  

            --- Getting time log and duty time [second time in]  
            SELECT @second_time_in = (SELECT TOP 1 Clock 
                                      FROM   hrms.AttendanceRecord 
                                      WHERE  [Date] = @built_date  
                                             AND Clock BETWEEN 
                                                 @from_second_time_in 
                                                 AND 
                                                 @to_second_time_in 
                                             AND UserID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, 
                                                               '00000') 
                                                               AS 
                                                               NVARCHAR(10)) 
                                      ORDER  BY ID ASC) 

            SELECT @duty_time_in = (SELECT D.BeginTime 
                                    FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                                           JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                                             ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                                           JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                                             ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                                           JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                                             ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
                                    WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast( 
                                           FORMAT(@counter, '00000') 
                                           AS 
                                           NVARCHAR(10)) 
                                           AND D.Remark = 'PM') 

            ---end getting log and duty time  
            --- Calculation result and status [second time in]  
            SELECT @result_time = Datediff (SECOND, @duty_time_in, 
                                  ​@second_time_in) 

            SELECT @hour = @result_time / 3600 

            SELECT @minute = ( @result_time % 3600 ) / 60 

            SELECT @second = ( @result_time % 3600 ) % 60 

            SELECT @status = CASE 
                               WHEN ( @second_time_in > @duty_time_in ) THEN ( 
                               N'ចូលយឺត(' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@hour, '00') AS NVARCHAR) + ':' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@minute, '00') AS NVARCHAR) 
                               + ':' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@second, '00') AS NVARCHAR) 
                               + N' វិនាទី)' ) 
                               ELSE '' 
                             END ---end calculation  
            --- Saving Result  
            INSERT INTO hrms.AnalyzedRecord  
            SELECT TOP 1 ID, 
                         DN, 
                         UserID, 
                         Clock, 
                         [Date], 
                         'In', 
                         VerifyMode, 
                         @status 
            FROM   hrms.AttendanceRecord 
            WHERE  [Date] = @built_date  
                   AND Clock BETWEEN @from_second_time_in AND @to_second_time_in 
                   AND UserID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
            ORDER  BY ID ASC ---end saving [3]  

            --- Getting time log and duty time [second time out]  
            SELECT @second_time_out = (SELECT TOP 1 Clock 
                                       FROM   hrms.AttendanceRecord 
                                       WHERE  [Date] = @built_date  
                                              AND Clock BETWEEN 
                                                  @from_second_time_out 
                                                  AND 
                                                  @to_second_time_out 
                                              AND UserID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, 
                                                                '00000' 
                                                                ) AS 
                                                                NVARCHAR(10)) 
                                       ORDER  BY ID DESC) 

            SELECT @duty_time_out = (SELECT D.EndTime 
                                     FROM   hrms.DutyTime AS D 
                                            JOIN hrms.[GroupDutyTime] AS GD 
                                              ON GD.DutyTimeID = D.DutyTimeID 
                                            JOIN hrms.[Group] AS G 
                                              ON G.GroupID = GD.GroupID 
                                            JOIN hrms.Employee AS E 
                                              ON E.GroupID = G.GroupID 
                                     WHERE  E.EmployeeID = Cast( 
                                            FORMAT(@counter, '00000' 
                                            ) AS 
                                            NVARCHAR(10)) 
                                            AND D.Remark = 'PM') 

            ---end getting log and duty time  
            --- Calculation result and status [second time out]  
            SELECT @result_time = Datediff (SECOND, @second_time_out, 
                                  ​@duty_time_out) 

            SELECT @hour = @result_time / 3600 

            SELECT @minute = ( @result_time % 3600 ) / 60 

            SELECT @second = ( @result_time % 3600 ) % 60 

            SELECT @status = CASE 
                               WHEN ( @second_time_out < @duty_time_out ) THEN ( 
                               N'ចេញមុន(' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@hour, '00') AS NVARCHAR) + ':' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@minute, '00') AS NVARCHAR) 
                               + ':' 
                               + Cast(FORMAT(@second, '00') AS NVARCHAR) 
                               + N' វិនាទី)' ) 
                               ELSE '' 
                             END ---end calculation  
            --- Saving Result  
            INSERT INTO hrms.AnalyzedRecord  
            SELECT TOP 1 ID, 
                         DN, 
                         UserID, 
                         Clock, 
                         [Date], 
                         'Out', 
                         VerifyMode, 
                         @status 
            FROM   hrms.AttendanceRecord 
            WHERE  [Date] = @built_date  
                   AND Clock BETWEEN @from_second_time_out AND 
                                     @to_second_time_out 
                   AND UserID = Cast(FORMAT(@counter, '00000') AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
            ORDER  BY ID DESC ---end saving [4]  
            SET @counter = @counter + 1 
        END 
    SET @date_step += 1
    SET @counter = 0
    END
        PRINT('Looping Date: ' + cast(@date_step as nvarchar(max)))
  /*** Generating dynamic script for monthly report ***/ 
  DECLARE @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX), 
          @sql_start  NVARCHAR(MAX), 
          @sql_end    NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SELECT @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT UserID ' 

  SELECT @date_range = Datediff(day, @date, Dateadd(MONTH, 1, @date)); 

  SELECT @date_step = 1; 

  SELECT @sql_start = ''; 

  SELECT @sql_end = ''; 

  WHILE @date_step <= @date_range 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @sql_start += ', ISNULL([' + Cast(Year(@date) AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
                             + '-' + Cast(Month(@date) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                             + '-' + Cast(@date_step AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '], '''')' 
                             + 'AS ' + '[' 
                             + Cast(Year(@date) AS NVARCHAR(max)) + '-' 
                             + Cast(Month(@date) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '-' 
                             + Cast(@date_step AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ']'; 

        SELECT @sql_end += '[' + Cast(Year(@date) AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
                           + '-' + Cast(Month(@date) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                           + '-' + Cast(@date_step AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                           + '], '; 

        SET @date_step +=1; 
    END 

  SELECT @sql += @sql_start 
                 + 'FROM hrms.AnalyzedRecord      PIVOT (MIN([Clock]) FOR [Date] IN(' 
                 + Substring(@sql_end, 1, (Len(@sql_end)-1)) 
                 + ')) AS P' 

  exec( @sql ); 


END 


truncate table hrms.AnalyzedRecord
declare @date_var date, @location_var nvarchar(max) 
select @date_var = DATEADD(month, -1, getdate()) 
select @location_var = 'KCL' 
exec [hrms].[GetMonthlyAttedance] @date_var, @location_var
```

The result of this code was:

[image]

I'm looking forward to seeing your recommendation. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I am getting the issue here? You need to do what exactly?

Comment: I want to query the record from database to create an attendance report using crosstab or pivot. And the above picture is the result that I can do.

Comment: So the picture is what you need, right?

Comment: The picture is the result of my query. What I want is what I have mention on top. Thanks for your interest. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (replace only this part in your code with the one below):

```
/*** Generating dynamic script for monthly report ***/ 
  DECLARE @sql        NVARCHAR(MAX), 
          @sql_start  NVARCHAR(MAX), 
          @sql_end    NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SELECT @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT UserID ' 

  SELECT @date_range = Datediff(day, @date, Dateadd(MONTH, 1, @date)); 

  SELECT @date_step = 1; 

  SELECT @sql_start = ''; 

  SELECT @sql_end = ''; 

  WHILE @date_step <= @date_range 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @sql_start += ', ISNULL([' + Cast(Year(@date) AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
                             + '-' + Cast(Month(@date) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                             + '-' + Cast(@date_step AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '], '''')' 
                             + 'AS ' + '[' 
                             + Cast(Year(@date) AS NVARCHAR(max)) + '-' 
                             + Cast(Month(@date) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '-' 
                             + Cast(@date_step AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ']'; 

        SELECT @sql_end += '[' + Cast(Year(@date) AS NVARCHAR(max)) 
                           + '-' + Cast(Month(@date) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                           + '-' + Cast(@date_step AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                           + '], '; 

        SET @date_step +=1; 
    END 

  SELECT @sql += @sql_start 
                 + 'FROM (SELECT DISTINCT UserID, [Clock], [date]  FROM hrms.AnalyzedRecord ) DS     PIVOT (MIN([Clock]) FOR [Date] IN(' 
                 + Substring(@sql_end, 1, (Len(@sql_end)-1)) 
                 + ')) AS P' 

  exec( @sql );
```

Comment: I have tried it. And this is the error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 474
Invalid column name 'Date'.
Msg 265, Level 16, State 1, Line 474
The column name "2018-6-1" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument.

Comment: Could you past me the dynamic statement which is build.

Comment: @SophartPhun What you need to do is to wrap your `SELECT` statement in `SELECT * FROM ( ... your select here ) DS` and then to append the `PIVOT` statement. Do you get the idea?

Comment: Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LzvgxXZSsQDsySqRp3dSxuhw4FyQfajo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have tried and checked it, but it comes up with the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176849/discussion-between-gotqn-and-sophart-phun).